# Xcode: constraining varying height UILabels to fixed size container

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, interface-builder, constraints

I’m building an iOS app which includes a quiz. Questions are displayed in the upper portion of the screen (see below). There are always five possible answers. The thing is: the answers are procedurally generated and vary in length, which leads to line breaks in the label sometimes.

[This is the current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1tel.png)

Maybe it’s hard to tell from the picture, but the spacing between the first and second and then between the second and third is not the same as I intend it to be.

[This is what I had in mind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Jth.png)

Essentially, I’d like the top- and bottommost labels to have the same space towards the container. The labels in the middle should all have the same spacing between each other, but should also adapt, if one of the labels gets bigger (when the size of a text is longer than the width and a line break occurs).

To achieve this, I tried the following:

- Organise the labels as a stack view:

  Nearly worked, the only problem I have here is, that the size of the
  labels is calculated after the stack view is displayed, which leads to wrong constraints/paddings/margins being applied to the (possibly) longer texts at runtime.
- Organise the labels with regular constraints

  I tried setting the
  priority of the constraints for the middle labels lower than
  that of the top- and bottommost ones, so those would be the ones
  to resize, if the labels enlarges, but it appears that at
  runtime one of those is chosen to shrink, whereas the others
  remain at their default size.

I'd really appreciate if you could help me out, constraints always seem to be a pain in my neck...

Comment: Each answer is in a UITextField? Or a UILabel? Do you want/need the font size to adjust?

Comment: They are UILabels, will change that in my question, thanks! The font size should stay the same across all answers.

Comment: OK - I added an answer with a link to an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed... I think UIStackView works fine, just have to set it up properly.

Also you may need to call .sizeToFit on the labels when you set the text.

I put up an example for you - the sizing is not exact, but you should be able to follow the technique...

https://github.com/DonMag/StackViewFun

Comment: You sir deserve a medal! Works like a charm, thanks a lot for putting together this tutorial, great work! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice in your case would indeed be to use a `UIStackView`. Then you have multiple option in solving this problem:

1. You can set the distribution of the `UIStackView` to `Fill Proportionally` and set a `Minimum Font Size` or `Minimum Font Scale` to your `UILabels`.
2. You can also set the distribution of the `UIStackView` to `Fill` and then manually specify the height of your containers. The `UILabels` should still have some `Minimum Font Size` or `Minimum Font Scale`.

**EDIT:**

I just realized you want to keep all `UILabels` to have the same font sizes. Then a possible solution would be to embed the `UIStackView` into a `UIScrollView` and constraint the `UIStackView's` `Leading`, `Trailing`, `Top` and `Bottom` constraints to the ones of the `ContentView` of the `UIScrollView.` In this way the height of the `UIScrollView` will adapt in accordance of the needed height by the `UIStackView`.

Hope this will help you!